# substitute string in php from another file

Tags: php, sed, awk, gettext

i have some old php files which i'd like to convert to use gettext.
those files have a content like this :

```
$LD = 'Some String';
$Another = 'some other ~n~ string';
```

i have to substitute all the $LD, $Another in the files where they are declared with something like :

```
_('Some string');
```

hacking a bit a created some sort of regexp to find the declarations, 
my aim was to use sed and awk to do the replaces..but i don't have any clue on how to do those substitutions ...

any help ...

Comment: You should show what you have so far.

Comment: so far i've come up with this : 
^\$\w+\s*(\[[0-9]*\])*\s*=\s*.*?;$
which does a decent job at finding 
$somevar = 'string' 
and even
$other[2] = 'another string';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -r $'s/(\$LD = )(\'.*\')(.*)/\\1_(\\2)\\3/' filename
```

Example:

```
$ echo "\$LD = 'Some String';" | sed -r $'s/(\$LD = )(\'.*\')(.*)/\\1_(\\2)\\3/'
$LD = _('Some String');
```

**Edit:**

This will look for and change both variables, the `-i` will make the change in-place:

```
sed -i -r $'s/(\$(LD|Another) = )(\'.*\')(.*)/\\1_(\\3)\\4/'
```

You can list more variable names separated by pipe characters.

Your `grep` command needs single quotes instead of backticks and a `-E` to use extended regexes. It also needs a filespec glob. The regex as you have basically says "Does this file have any variable definitions?" It says to look for any variable that:

- starts at the beginning of the line with no whitespace before it
- has zero or more array subscripts consisting of zero or more digits (which would include a null subscript, thus an array append)
- ignore any associative array assignments (`$array["key"]=value`)
- the line must end in a semicolon
- I'm not sure what the `?` is intended to do

This fails if the variable assignment:

- occurs after some whitespace
- uses an alpha key or a variable as a key
- occurs on a line with other statements
- has any trailing whitespace
- possibly others

You might need to make your regex more robust or simpler or just assume that any PHP file will have a variable assignment and let `sed` look for and change just the variables of interest.

In order for your `grep` to have files to process, you need to specify which files to look at:

```
grep -E -i -R 'your regex' * | sed ...
```

Or, if you let `sed` do it:

```
find . -name "*.php" | sed ...
```

Also, a tool called [`ack` is better than `grep`](http://betterthangrep.com/) for finding stuff in code files.

In any case, especially if you use the in-place option, *I strongly recommend test runs (and backups).*

Comment: so for looking in multiple files and doing a replace i'd need something like :
grep -i -R `^\$\w+\s*(\[[0-9]*\])*\s*=\s*.*?;$` | sed -r $'s/(\$LD = )(\'.*\')(.*)/\\1_(\\2)\\3/'